# Was the UK government capable of confirming in 2016 if I was in Bulgaria?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel

I'm actually asking as research for a novel which is set in 2016.

If a UK citizen was reported missing abroad, would the UK authorities be able to check using name and DOB only, and discover that someone with those details was definitely in Bulgaria at that time? (NB- Bulgaria is not in the Schengen Zone, so passport checks are required at all borders).

Comment: Name and DOB are not so unique, and Bulgaria use Cyrillic, so creating problem with transliteration (on databases). And "missing" is not a crime (so to ask help). They may find him (bank card, phone, etc.), or if they knew much more about him (last known address in Bulgaria). Note: Bulgaria may ask UK for confirmation of validity of a passport, if the UK citizen need it for some reason (residence, police check, etc.)

Comment: Are you asking if the UK Passport Authority is notified when a UK passport is scanned at a foreign passport control (either immigration or emigration)? I think the answer to that is no, but I'm not certain.

Comment: If your novel take place in the past (up to mid 1970's): they would not know that a UK citizen had left or returned to the UK since only 3rd country nationals were required to fill out the boarding cards and had their passports stamped.

Comment: on the NB: UK was never part of the Schengen Zone, so passport checks are still required to this day to go from Schengen (except Republic of Ireland) to UK and vice versa. There are passport controls in the airports, train stations, Chunnel entrances and ferry checkpoints

Comment: press 'Edit' and add 'set in 2016' to the end of the first line.

Comment: Thank you for the replies so far. I should've said, the book is set in 2016. I guess this is actually a 2-part question: 1) Would the UK authorities be able to use name and date of birth to find a UK citizen's passport details, and 2) would they then be able to check with the Bulgarian authorities and discover that this passport was scanned when the missing person entered the country, and confirm that there is no exit scan, indicating that the person has not left the country?

Comment: Yes, absolutely the UK could find UK passport details based on name and DOB. Not every agency is allowed to do it, but with a reason it can be found. Likewise, even if Bulgaria doesn't send details of all UK citizens when they enter or leave (I believe it doesn't) they might well respond to a request to find out if a UK citizen entered or left Bulgaria in a certain timeframe. Depending on local laws, and if they thought the reason for the request was legal and good enough. "Reported missing and believed to be the victim of a crime" or "wanted for a crime" are probably good reasons.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza The Republic of Ireland is not (currently) in the Schengen area either.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should consider that name and date of birth is not enough to uniquely identify a person. Even *if* Bulgarian authorities recorded entries and exits, they could with the name and DOB only confirm or reject that *a* UK citizen with that name and DOB was currently present in Bulgaria at any time. It would not be possible to find out if it is the person you are actually looking for.

IANAL and I am not familiar with Bulgarian record keeping of foreign visitors, but when it comes to the question if a UK citizen would generate entry and exit records passing a Bulgarian bolder in 2016, I would with 99.9% certainty say no. UK and Bulgaria were at that time both members of the EU (UK not being a Schengen member is not significant here) and it would be a breach of EU data protection laws if one country with no reason tracked the movement of other EU citizens.

Comment: I'd add that data protection laws usually don't apply (or are routinely ignored) to state security organizations like the MI-6. Its possible that there's a secret database somewhere that tracks all of this data covertly. If OP is writing a spy novel they could assume such a a database exists.

Comment: @JonathanReez In the EU, such laws also apply to the authorities. If they follow the laws is of course another thing, but security organizations do not have a blanket exception. It would of course also not be possible that Bulgarian legislation allows their authorities to systematically violate the privacy rights of *other* EU citizens visiting Bulgaria. For a fictional novel, the author can of course write anything he likes, but I understood the question as if OP wanted to fact check his plan.

Comment: But, when an EU citizen travels outside the Schengen zone, their passport does get scanned. I can recall many experiences of this happening pre-Brexit. Surely this leaves a record of where they've entered/left the Schengen zone?  Now I think of it, my partner once visited the Bulgarian traffic police to apply for a Bulgarian driver's licence (long story, and not relevant here) and the police officer took her passport and was able to view the dates of recent land border crossings to Greece and Serbia.

Comment: @Alex I am not sure why you think the Schengen area is relevant for the question, neither UK nor Bulgaria has ever been a part of it. Still, what you are saying is wrong. EU passports *may* be scanned when the holder leaves or enters the Schengen area, they do not have to. And surely not, when the passports are scanned, there is made no record of that.

Comment: @Tor, the Schengen area is relevant to my question because I'm trying to ascertain whether it is possible for a law enforcement authority to determine that a foreign national (or indeed a Bulgarian national) is definitely in Bulgaria at a particular moment. Since Bulgaria is not in the Schengen zone, there is passport control at all of its international borders.

Comment: For example, if my character disappeared while backpacking in the Schengen zone, they could theoretically be in any country within the zone. But, if my character was last heard of in Bulgaria, I believe it may be possible to determine that they are still in Bulgaria, and have not either crossed a land border into Greece, Turkey, Serbia or Romania, or flown to any other country.

Comment: - "they do not have to." - do you have evidence for this, please? I'm trying to fact check.  "And surely not, when the passports are scanned, there is made no record of that." - as I said above, a traffic policeman was able to scan my partner's passport and view the dates of recent land border crossings to Greece and Serbia.

Comment: @Alex Comments here are not to conduct endless discussions, but to answer your last questions: You can find the rules for when passports must, may and must not be scanned at the external borders in the Schengen Borders Code. There is no record made of the scan simply because there exists no register to put that record into. The new EES register will enter into operation some time in 2022 and keep records of non EU/EEA citizens crossing external Schengen borders, but also in this register, no EU/EEA citizens will be recorded.